# Mapping custom domain to Windows Azure CDN does not working

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cdn

I've created an Windows Azure Blob Storage and associated a Windows Azure CDN service.
I map custom domain to Azure CDN. After veryfication is completed for my custom domain, I've created CNAME record that map static.codeinstinct.pro to az412526.vo.msecnd.net.

As a result, I have 3 links:
codeinstinct.blob.core.windows.net/test/trouble.gif
az412526.vo.msecnd.net/test/trouble.gif
static.codeinstinct.pro/test/trouble.gif

First 2 links is work, but the last one doesn't (returns a 400 'Bad request' error).

I try to get details DNS name of custom domain. It's look like:
;; QUESTION SECTION: 
;static.codeinstinct.pro.   IN  CNAME
;; ANSWER SECTION:
static.codeinstinct.pro. 600    IN  CNAME   az412526.vo.msecnd.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
codeinstinct.pro.   86399   IN  NS  ns01.parking.ru.
codeinstinct.pro.   86399   IN  NS  ns11.parking.ru.

Why it is not working?

Comment: DNS change propagation may take up to 24 hours. I would recommend waiting a bit longer.

Comment: Appropriate CNAME record has been added 3 days ago.

Comment: Ya, I did this and it took literally 5 minutes with a CNAME to propagate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the custom domain in the Azure portal - see [How to Map CDN Content to a Custom Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg680307.aspx)

Comment: > enable the custom domain - You mean the validate domain steps?

Comment: I have read this walk-through once, then twice, then... and cannot find step which I left undone or done incorrectly.

Comment: did you validate your domain in the Azure Portal?  Did you follow/complete all the steps?

Comment: Yes, I validated my custom domain. After validation domain status have been 'allowed'. Other steps also have been completed.

Comment: Same here, still getting 400 Bad Request. Even Dig (http://digwebinterface.com) shows the propagation changes being reflected. What else could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I removed all what I had created: custom domain (with CNAME records), then Azure CDN enpoint. Then I recreated what I had removed and... all work!